# Need odbc driver in dockerfile for my r shiny app

Tags: r, docker, shiny, dockerfile, odbc

I'm making a R shiny app, which calls the database (SQL Server) using DBI and odbc and displays a table. My app works perfectly on my local machine. However, when I tried to dockerize the shiny app, it just failed to start. No clue why that does not work.

I feel like I might need to install the odbc drive in my dockerfile. Maybe I'm also missing something else...

I'm new to docker. Appreciate it if someone can show how I can modify my dockerfile so that my shiny app also works as docker container.

below is my dockerfile:

```
# Base image https://hub.docker.com/u/rocker/
FROM rocker/shiny:latest

# system libraries of general use
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install \
    libxml2-dev \
    libcairo2-dev \
    libsqlite3-dev \
    libmariadbd-dev \
    libpq-dev \
    libssh2-1-dev \
    unixodbc-dev \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev \
    libssl-dev

## update system libraries
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get clean

# Install R packages that are required
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('dplyr','DT', 'DBI', 'odbc'), repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
    
# Copy configuration files into the Docker image
COPY shiny-server.conf  /etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf
COPY /app /srv/shiny-server/

# Make the ShinyApp available at port 80
EXPOSE 80

# Copy further configuration files into the Docker image
COPY shiny-server.sh /usr/bin/shiny-server.sh

CMD ["/usr/bin/shiny-server.sh"]
```

below is my shiny ui.r:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    
    titlePanel("Database table"),    
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(),
        mainPanel(
            fluidRow (
                column(12, DT::dataTableOutput('datatable')) )
        )
    )
)
```

my server.r

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    conn <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                           Driver = "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
                           Server = 'xxxxxx',
                           Database = "xxxxxx",
                           UID = "xxxxxx",
                           PWD = 'xxxxxxx',
                           port=1433)
    df = dbGetQuery(conn, "SELECT * FROM myTable")
    dbDisconnect(conn)    
    output$datatable <- DT::renderDataTable({
        DT::datatable(df)
    })
}
```

global.r:

```
library(shiny)
library(DBI)
library(odbc)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
```

Comment: I think we're missing a piece, are you running a SQL server container, or is the R container supposed to talk to SQL server on your host machine? Also: "However, when I tried to dockerize the shiny app, it just failed to start." - can we see a screenshot of what is failing? What happens if you try and run the R program from within the container manually? Is the app not working or is docker failing to start? I would wager the issue is DB connectivity but it's hard to be certain just based on that description. Might be worth adding in error handling in the R script. Let us know how you go

Answer (score 2):

If it throws the error like "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server" cannot be found, perhaps you haven't installed the ODBC driver in your Dockerfile.

I had the same issue, but it was solved for me when putting this in my Dockerfile: https://community.rstudio.com/t/odbc-drivers-docker/32714.

Answer (score 0):

I still think we don't have enough information (it isn't ideal that we can't see the specific error message confirming that it is a connectivity issue between the Docker container and the SQL Server), but I'll state my assumptions and give this a shot.

You mentioned that you have this stack running locally without issue, and it's only when you move the R application into a container that it isn't working. This leads me to think that your SQL Server instance is running locally.

Once again, it's hard to be certain as in `server.r`. You've censored out the database endpoint (`Server = 'xxxxxx',`). If it is an external endpoint it makes sense to censor it, but if it is an internal/localhost address this could be useful.

I'm not familiar with this stack, but from what I've read you've done the right thing in regards to ODBC - you installed the system packages, installed the R libraries, and included the R libraries. Looking at this article it seems like it should be correct: https://nhsrcommunity.com/blog/sql-server-database-connections-in-r/

So, my theory is that your server configuration is still pointing at `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` despite being in a Docker container (they no longer share the same loopback/localhost!).

So please try updating your `server.r` database endpoint to `Server = 'host.docker.internal',`

I think there's a decent chance this is the issue, please refer to this thread for a lot more information about connecting a Docker container to a host service: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24326540/3080207, `host.docker.internal` should work, but I think it may depend on the OS you are running and the version of Docker you are running.

If I'm way off the mark, please provide more information :)